# Replace last ", " with " & "

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, replace

I am trying to do the following task

[Task Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/53368a47e38700bd8300030d/train/javascript)

This is my solution

```
function list(names){
  return names.map(x => x.name).join(',').replace("," , "&");
}
```

I want to replace the last **comma** with **&**.

I found this solution **replace(/, (?!.*, )/ , "&")** on the Internet, however, it does not work for me and I do not understand it.

Is it possible to solve this problem in a different way using the method replace?

Comment: Please post the task as text in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex for this. You can simply slice the array to contain all but the last element, then join it on `,` and append the last item separating it with `&` as the following snippet shows.

```js
var myNames = [{name:"Smith"},{name:"John"},{name:"Jack"},{name:"Emma"}]

console.log(list(myNames))

function list(names){
  var n = names.map(x => x.name)
  return n.slice(0,-1).join(',') + '&' + n.slice(-1);
}
```

If there's a possibility of there only being 1 name, you can use the following to ensure the result doesn't return something like `&name`:

```
return (n.length > 1 ? n.slice(0,-1).join(',') + '&' : '') + n.slice(-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

It almost works, only you have to remove the extra whitespace in the regex because that has meaning.

Change

```
replace(/, (?!.*, )/ , "&")
..........^......^.........
whitespaces
```

to

`.replace(/,(?!.*,)/, "&")`

This part `,(?!.*,)` matches a comma and uses a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!.*,` to assert that what follows does not contain a comma. That will make sure that the last comma is matched.

As [SourceOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8331815/sourceoverflow) points out this will for the example data but will not work when there is a comma in the name itself.

```js
function list(names){
    return names.map(x => x.name).join(',').replace(/,(?!.*,)/ , "&");
}
console.log(list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'} ]));
```

That will result in:

> Bart,Lisa&Maggie

Comment: This is not correct, if someone has a `,` in his name

Comment: @SourceOverflow That is correct. I have added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```js
function list(names) {
  return names.map(x => x.name).join(', ').replace(/,([^,]*)$/, ' &$1');
}

console.log(list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'} ]));
// returns 'Bart, Lisa & Maggie'

console.log(list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'} ]));
// returns 'Bart & Lisa'

console.log(list([ {name: 'Bart'} ]));
// returns 'Bart'

console.log(list([]));
// returns ''
```